# RabbitMQ - High Availability Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a RabbitMQ Cluster with two nodes and a listener (connected in both) that declares a Queue (binding with a topic exchange). The queue was declared (apparently at node 1) and replicated to node 2 (as expected). So far so good.

But when the node 1 goes down, the queue is deleted from node 2, crashing my listener. Here is the queue parameters:

- exclusive="false"
- durable="true"
- auto-delete="false"

Clearly it does not seem to be a correct high availability behavior. The question is how can I create this queue and keep it available when at least 1 node is up (no matter wich one)?

Comment: Have a look on the rabbit management UI to make sure the queue is declared as expected.

Comment: @GaryRussell: Yes it is listed as declared, but in state "Down". When I click on it, this message appears: "The object you clicked on was not found; it may have been deleted on the server"

Comment: How are you making it HA? Via a policy or with queue declaration arguments? Show your configuration.

Comment: Using policy. I just found the solution: added "ha-sync-mode:  automatic" into policy definition and it works. Thanks!